# Smartsheet Error Objects - Attribute Error

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to grab all of the cell history of a given sheet and spit it out to a csv. The code works on one sheet but not on another. When I get to the revision section of the code, I get a bunch of attribute errors.  The following code is in the guts of a function cycling through the cells of a sheet.

Error reads `'Error' object has no attribute 'data'`

The weirdest part is that the errors are not found consistently. As in, cycling through the same sheet, different cells will pop the error than when I ran the script last time. I am catching the Attribute Error, but that doesn't really solve the problem.  Help?

```
            #get the cell history
            action = smartsheet.Cells.get_cell_history(
                sheetid,
                row.id,
                columns[c].id,
                #include_all=True
                )

            try:
                revisions = action.data

            except AttributeError as inst:
                print('found Attribute error in this cell:')
                print(inst)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because the cell has no history. You'll need to do a safety check to verify that the attribute exists before accessing it.

```
if not hasattr(action, 'data'):
    print('no history found')
```

You may be polling the API too rapidly, which is why sometimes values aren't returned. From the [API documentation](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#get-cell-history):

> This is a resource-intensive operation and incurs 10 additional requests against the rate limit.

Make sure you're handling any returned errors appropriately to see if this is the case.